# Cleaner way to bind angular vm to table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating a table and repeating it for each item in my viewmodel and am looking for a cleaner way to write this.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4" ng-repeat="x in vm.visibleOptions">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    Option <span ng-bind="x.OptionNumber"></span> - <span ng-bind="x.OptionName"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any advice would be helpful as I dove head first into angular for a new project.

Comment: Is there a more proper way to do this?

Comment: What would be `a cleaner way to write this` for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaner is pretty subjective, but if you can do it more concisely with:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4" ng-repeat="x in vm.visibleOptions">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    Option {{x.OptionNumber}} - {{x.OptionName}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then also add the CSS for ng-cloak to your index.html file.

```
<style>
        [ng\:cloak],
        [ng-cloak],
        [data-ng-cloak],
        [x-ng-cloak],
        .ng-cloak,
        .x-ng-cloak {
            display: none !important;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: the table has grown larger already, when I use {{}} the code flashes on the screen even if i use ng-cloak.

Comment: Did you define the CSS for ng-cloak in your index.html file?

Comment: I did not, I didn't know you had to do that!

Comment: Cool. I am going to update the answer so that it reflects that as well.